# Delete multiple items from a ToolStrip

Tags: vb.net

I have make a ToolStrip works like windows task bar. When user opens a new form, a label with form's icon appears on ToolStrip as new label item. I also have a button that closes all forms at once. But I want to remove every relevant label too, so I added this into the click event...

```
For Each mdichildlabel As ToolStripLabel In Me.BottomToolStrip.Items
    If mdichildlabel.Name = "NewLabel" Then
        BottomToolStrip.Items.Remove(mdichildlabel)
    End If
Next
```

But I get this error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work doesn't tell us what you are seeing that is not working.

Generally, you can't modify a collection while for-eaching it because of the changing index positions.  Try iterating over it backwards:

```
For i As Integer = Me.BottomToolStrip.Items.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
  If Me.BottomToolStrip.Items(i).Name = "NewLabel" Then
    Me.BottomToolStrip.Items.RemoveAt(i)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I changed the "doesn't work" sentence with the error I was getting...